# get rejected count of array

Tags: ruby

A little intimidated by reject!, delete_if, select, keep_if, etc.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject

What is the shortest way to modify an array deleting away elements that don't match a condition in the {} block, while printing the count of those *lost* elements?

eg.

```
  puts "Filtered out #{(siglist.reject!{|r| r[:ret] < $retmin }).size} whose :ret < retmin(#{$retmin})"
```

Seems to only print the number of **surviving** elements in the array after the reject.

Comment: I think what originally threw me off, was the CSV class `.delete_if` which (serendipitously for me) always returns an array of the deleted elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly low-tech, but you could find the number of rejected values by the difference in length of the array before and after:

```
previous_length = siglist.size
puts "Filtered out #{previous_length - (siglist.reject!{|r| r[:ret] < $retmin }).size} whose :ret < retmin(#{$retmin})"
```

Comment: True. The inline version could be `puts "killed: #{(a=siglist).size - (a.reject!{|r| r[:ret] < $retmin }).size} because they stink"` or maybe without the `a` copy altogether?

Comment: Right on - I don't think the copy's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Non-Bang Methods to Create a New Array for Comparison

The best way I can think of to deal with this is to leave the original array intact for comparison. For example:

```
array = *(1..9)
new_array = array.reject { |i| i.odd? }
puts "Threw away #{ array.count - new_array.count } elements"
# => Threw away 5 elements
```

Alternatively, you can use set operations on the arrays. It's shorter to type, but the end result is the same:

```
array - new_array
# => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

puts "Threw away %d elements" % (array - new_array).count
# => Threw away 5 elements
```

In other words, *how* you count the rejected elements is up to you, but comparing two arrays is the easiest way I know to track the elements that were rejected.